# Component is undefined in window.addEventListener in Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, navigation, browser

I'm not sure if I am missing a syntax but I have the following component and javascript. I'm trying to execute some javascript in the "popstate" callback but for some reason, the "component" is undefined. The popstate is the history API, essentially, I am trying to trigger a code when the user clicks the browser's back or forward button.

MyComponent.cmp

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
<aura:attribute name="displayDetail" type="boolean" default="false" access="global" />
<lightning:button label="View Details" onclick="{!c.viewDetails}"/>
```

MyComponentController.js

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", $A.getCallback(function () {
        console.log(component.get('v.displayDetail')); //This is coming out as "undefined", but i am expecting it to be “false”
    }));
   
},
viewDetails : function(component, event, helper) {

    history.pushState({'recordNo':1}, 'View Detail','/poc/s/browser-navigation');
}
```

Edit:

i am expecting it to be “false”, but I am getting “undefined”. I am trying to execute a javascript code in that callback, for example, helper.displayDetails(component, event.state.recordNo); but the “component” itself is getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the context change because the event handler is not executed not in the same context as the component itself you need to somehow pass `component` into the handler here are a few options.

1. Probably won't work, but you can try => (arrow function), it doesn't change scope the same way `function` does.

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", $A.getCallback(() => {
        console.log(component.get('v.displayDetail')); //This is coming out as "undefined", but i am expecting it to be “false”
    }));
   
},
```

2. Use `bind` to pass component as part of the context

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", $A.getCallback(function() {
        console.log(this.get('v.displayDetail')); //This is coming out as "undefined", but i am expecting it to be “false”
    }.bind(component)));

},
```

since you bind your context to the component in the call back you can use `this` instead of `component`. From what I remember this the method I was usually using

Comment: Thanks ytiq, i tried both approach you recommended but unfortunately, neither worked.

Comment: ok, I'll try it tomorrow and update the answer with correct option

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue, it works fine for me. and I get the console value as false. have placed the component on Record page, using Chrome Version 88.0.4324.190.
Can you check with the Chrome browser if you haven't tried already.

getting console message **Value on popstate: false**

Please find the the exact code I have copied from question.

```
({
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", $A.getCallback(function () {
        console.log('>>Value on popstate: '+component.get('v.displayDetail')); 
        }));
},


viewDetails : function(component, event, helper) {
    history.pushState({'recordNo':1}, 'View Detail','/poc/s/browser-navigation');
}
})
```

.cmp file:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
<aura:attribute name="displayDetail" type="boolean" default="false" access="global" />
<lightning:button label="View Details" onclick="{!c.viewDetails}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: have you tried this in community? And I am on the latest Chrome Version 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) (64-bit). Also I tried in other browsers like firefox and edge as well. So I dont think its a browser issue.

Comment: No, I haven't tried in Community. Can you specify where you place this component to replicate the exact case.

Comment: I am using the component in the Salesforce Community. Basically, I went to Setup--> Digital Experiences --> Sites (formerly the Communities Builder) and then I created a blank page, and dragged/added that component into the new community page.